# S3 URL directly in Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using S3 to save the images of my web-tool. At the moment I am saving the key ('images/x/y.jpg') to the database.

To get the URL of the file I am doing this:

```
Store::cloud()->url(key)
```

Is it possible, to do this step to convert the key to an url directly in a model? Is there a "preprocess"-function which I can overwrite in Laravel models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

**1. Using Accessors**

Store the relative path in the database but access the full path through [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) like so:

```
public function getFullUrlAttribute($relUrl) {
    return config('filesystems.asset_url') . $relUrl;
}
```

**2. Using a helper**

Define a helper like so:

```
function getAssetUrl($relUrl)
```

However in both cases you would have to define the path in your config file. This does give you the flexibility to later on use a CDN like Cloudfront. All you would have to do is then change the config

Comment: The accessor is exactly the "preprocess" I want to do. Thank you!